# Which templates support database reverse engineering?

Tags: database, visio

I have Visio 2016 professional installed, which by all my research should support database reverse engineering.

Every guide I find says to go to the Software and Database category and select "Database Model Diagram" for the Database tab to pop up with the option for reverse engineering.

I do not see this template in my list available, and the one's I've tried don't make the Database tab visible. Am I missing something from my list, or which one would allow this functionality? If I have one that supports the functionality, how would I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The database reverse engineering code was removed in Visio Professional 2016 because of some issues, but it was announced late last year that it will be returning this year. In the meantime, you may find my following blog useful : [Creating a schema from Visio External Data Recordsets](http://blog.bvisual.net/2014/03/26/creating-a-schema-from-visio-external-data-record-sets/)

Comment: If you can provide a citation for them having removed it from 2016 or it returning later this year I'll mark this answer correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Database reverse engineering was actually removed in Visio 2013 - https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Discontinued-features-and-changed-functionality-in-Visio-2013-6e883c38-a597-418a-9e27-11f73a673b5c

Comment: Sajan Parihar, Microsoft Corporation, at Microsoft Convergence 2015 EMEA in November, presented a slide that Database Reverse Engineering is work in progress

Comment: Is there a link with followup about that feature ?

Comment: @DavidParker Is it back in 2016 yet?

Comment: Apparently there is a preview available in the Office Insider program now:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/visio-data-model-diagram-preview/569fd997-c2d4-49e5-91be-400084c8c975
I've filled out the survey and in the Slow Insider update channel but haven't seen or figured out how to access the feature yet.

Answer (score 5):

The Visio Add-in for Database Modeling is available as a separate download for **Visio Pro for Office 365 only**.

The package is available for download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54527).
Info on system requirements, installation, and usage is [here](https://support.office.com/client/FB034862-ACFC-45BC-88B2-F33D1E1F8614)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, install an earlier version of Visio (2007).

Comment: ..or Visio 2010. It is not available in Visio 2013 or 2016.

Comment: Could someone please advise, if it would it be the Professional or Standard version of Visio 2010 that would have the reverse engineering capability?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ain't gonna happen, unless you use 365. Grrr...[image: Screen Shot - Visio Desktop not supported]

Comment: You could post the link instead of a screenshot :)

Comment: I have 365 and it's still not available.